# How to get summary from wikipedia for different companies?

Tags: php, api, wikipedia

I am trying to get the summary paragraph for a user entered company from Wikipedia.

So for example, if the user enters Google, I need to display the summary paragraph for Google.

The code I am using at the moment:

```
// action=parse: get parsed text
// page=$input
// format=json: in json format
// prop=text: send the text content of the article
// section=0: top content of the page

$url = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&page=$input&format=json&prop=text&section=0';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "TestScript"); // required by wikipedia.org server; use YOUR user agent with YOUR contact information. (otherwise your IP might get blocked)
$c = curl_exec($ch);

$json = json_decode($c);

$content = $json->{'parse'}->{'text'}->{'*'}; // get the main text content of the query (it's parsed HTML)

// pattern for first match of a paragraph
$pattern = '#<p>(.*)</p>#Us'; // http://www.phpbuilder.com/board/showthread.php?t=10352690
if(preg_match($pattern, $content, $matches))
{
    // print $matches[0]; // content of the first paragraph (including wrapping <p> tag)
    print strip_tags($matches[1]); // Content of the first paragraph without the HTML tags.
}
```

Which works if `$input = "Zynga"` but not if `$input = "Google"`as it returns "reference: [4]."

Comment: It seems you should look in the DOM for a `<table class="infobox vcard" ...>` By the way, I think you also need to display CC licence and WP as source

Answer (score 0):

You could use `action=query&prop=extracts` instead with the `exintro=` option. E.g.
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&format=json&exlimit=1&exintro=&explaintext=&titles=Google
for Google.

This should remove most of the undesired formatting such as references.